# How to set values to placeholders in log4j.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

I am using spring/hibernate application. i am using log4j for logging. the problem is i need to place a placeholder in log4j.properties file and i need to set the value to the place holder based on the environment(Dev, UAT or Production).

```
Environment=${environment}
```

is it possible? Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the variable and value either by command line or set environment variable like below.

```
-DEnvironment=dev
```

then you can use this in log file like :

```
Environment=${Environment}
```

Comment: Might need to look at the case of environment vs Environment here

Comment: @amicngh, Thanks for ur reply. environment variables we have system variables and user variables(by right click on mycomputer->properties->Advanced->environmentvariables). where should i set? Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403 . do not set like that.If running java application then pass it like java -DEnvironment=dev HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use seperate keys, and pick the right one at runtime?

```
Environment.dev=Development
Environment.prod=Production
Environment.qa=QA

bundle.getKey(ENVIRONMENT_KEY_PREFIX + ".dev");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. where do i need to place the below properties? Environment.dev=Development
Environment.prod=Production
Environment.qa=QA

Comment: I'm not sure but i might have misread what you're asking.  WHy would need a placeholder in the log4 properties file?  That's something that should be relatively environment specific, and should be setup by whoever's installing the app.  My answer assumes you want logout the environment name in the log itself.